# Significado de «Fd.»

Tags: historia, abreviaturas, identificación-de-término

En *La escuadra chilena en México* (1971) está reproducido un documento del Archivo General de Indias «sobre la captura de la "Cazadora" por la goleta "Chilena"» que léese así:

> Noticia de los individuos que tomaron partido en la goleta *Chilena*, Corsario.
>
> - Primer guardia, Juan Portugues
> - Marinero, José Portugues
> - Mozo, Pedro Lamas
> - Fd. José Moya
> - Fd. José Ma. Tauma
> - Fd. José Marcial, Acapulqueño
> - Fd. Estanislao Fernandez
> - José del Carmen, Esclavo
>
> Corrijos, marzo 21 de 1819 — Manuel Ceballos

En este sitio: https://studylib.es/doc/8407490/lopez-urrutia---portal-barcos-do-brasil puede encontrarse el listado en cuestión en la página 80 (páginas 116/117 del libro)

[image: foto 1]
[image: foto 2]

¿Qué será **Fd.**?

Comment: No consigo encontrar nada sobre qué puede ser eso, pero se me ocurre que siendo las profesiones de mozo y marinero las más abundantes en una goleta, ¿es posible que no sea "fd" sino "id", la abreviatura de "ídem"? Eso indicaría que cada línea con "id" sería la misma profesión que la línea anterior.

Comment: @Charlie Me parece una buena deducción. Inclusive "Corrijos" parece ser un error: debería ser "Corrijas" (Hacienda de Corrijas). Si consideramos que la lista va de mayor (primer guardia) a menor (esclavo), "Fd." no podría ser un título. Además, es difícil imaginar un puesto intermedio entre "mozo" y "esclavo".

Comment: @Charlie Es claramente _Fd,_ ([link](https://books.google.cl/books?hl=es&id=3GEKAQAAIAAJ&dq=tripulacion+marinero+mozo+guardia+fd&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=fd))

Comment: ¿Puede ser "finado"?

Comment: @Rodrigo El libro transcribe un documento antiguo escrito a mano. Mi hipótesis es que, al igual que el autor escribió "Corrijos" en lugar de "Corrijas" (vio una "o" donde había una "a"), leyó "Fd" donde el documento original decía "Id". Sería interesante examinar la caligrafía de ese documento y ver cómo están escritas las "i" mayúsculas. No creo que haya otro modo de evacuar la duda.

Answer (score 1):

La sigla "Fd." parece corresponder al rango de

> "Fuerza de desembarco" o su equivalente "infante de marina"

La literatura naval bélica comprende elementos de asalto anfibio (agua y tierra) para lo cual hay una categoría especial de infantería de marina(una especie de soldado de tierra en la flota) para las operaciones al llegar a las costas.

La sigla aparece constar en varios documentos sobre el tema naval/militar (mencionado en [éste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw3JX.png) o [aquí](https://armada.defensa.gob.es/archivo/mardigitalrevistas/boletininfanteria/2008/200804.pdf#page=70))

La lectura somera del documento referido (sobre acciones marinas de corsarios chilenos y argentinos a principios de 1800) da un contexto del sentido militar de esa goleta, por lo que es perfectamente entendible que se refiere al uso de soldados de tierra (con lo que poder interpretar a "Fd." como 'fuerza de desembarco')

[image]

Esto encontré en el [Reglamento: abreviaturas y signos convencionales para uso de las Fuerzas Armadas](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=HnKkp6Ygou8C&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Fd%22)
[image: abreviación militar de FD]

Véase esta cita 
[image: *mención a fuerzas de desembarco*]

Answer (score -3):

Fd del latin

> Fidei Defensor

quiere decir "Defensor de la fe" es un titulo complementario de monarcas ingleses, después británicos
En la actualidad la reina de Reino unido,  Isabel II lleva el título: «Isabel II, por la Gracia de Dios, Reina del Reino Unido de Gran Bretaña e Irlanda del Norte y de sus otros Reinos y Territorios, Jefa de la Mancomunidad de Naciones, Defensora de la Fe»
El título «Defensor de la Fe» refleja la posición del soberano como Gobernador Supremo de la Iglesia de Inglaterra, que queda así formalmente en una posición superior a la del arzobispo de Canterbury.

En la mayoría de los territorios de la [Mancomunidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancomunidad_de_Naciones) la frase no aparece en el título tradicional del monarca, mientras que sí se mantiene la frase inicial por la [Gracia de Dios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracia_divina).

Comment: Esto es un plagio de la Wikipedia que no guarda relación con lo que se está preguntando. ¿Tú crees en serio que entre un mozo y un esclavo van cuatro "defensores de la fe", encima puesto en latín?

Comment: Fd Jose moya segun wikipedia
"Independiente Santa Fe"